# How is the equation $z=xy$ a hyperbolic paraboloid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hyperbolic-geometry

The general equation for a hyperbolic paraboloid is $z - z_{0} = \frac{(x - x_{0})^{2}}{a^{2}} -\frac{(y - y_{0})^{2}}{b^{2}}$. How is the equation $z=xy$ a hyperbolic paraboloid? Is there any algebra that can be applied to it to get its general form?

Comment: $$xy=\frac{(x+y)^2}4-\frac{(x-y)^4}{4}.$$

Comment: Something like $z'=z-z_0$, $x'=x\cos q+y\sin q$, $y'=x\sin q -y\cos q$?

Comment: Geometrically the equation $z=xy$ describes a hyperbolic paraboloid: the cross-section of $z=xy$ in the plane $y=x$ is a parabola opening upward with vertex at the origin, its cross-section in the plane $y=-x$ is a parabola opening downward with vertex at the origin, and cross-sections parallel to the $xy$ plane are hyperbolas whose asymptotes are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes.  Lord Shark's comment indicates that the change of variables $x=u+v$, $y=u-v$ (rotating the $xy$ plane and stretching a factor of $\sqrt{2}$) turns a standard hyperbolic paraboloid into $z=xy$.

Comment: Rotate by 45°, just as you might to get the hyperbola $xy=1$ into standard form.